# How customize a generic persistence lifecycle for CRUD operations in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to customize the hibernate's CRUD operations to execute some extra operations. My problem is, I do not have access to change the entities implementation and I need to persist extra metadata for these entities. For example:

```java
@Entity
class Entity1 {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String attr1;

}

@Entity
class Entity2 {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String attr1;

    private String attr2;
}
```

`Entity1` and `Entity2` are persisted in their own tables, thats fine, but I need to persist a metadata information, lets say `forced = [true|false]`, that describes if a given `String` attribute was forced or not. This information will be applied over the whole system, it means, for all entities with `String` attributes it should be possible to indentify it their String attributes were forced or not.

In my case, I can identify what instances and attributes were forced or not in runtime, this information is easily acessible in case I must implement some callback listener or interceptor. My idea is to persist these metadata information in a separate table, lets say `FORCED_ATTRIBUTES`, that has three columns (two to identify the entity and attributes changed and another one to define if the value was changed or not).

Is it possible to get such functionality without change these entities (`Entity1` and `Entity2`)?